# Использование fabric.js + web font loader

Tags: javascript, canvas, шрифты, fabricjs

Использую fabric.js и несколько кастомных шрифтов для своего приложения. Шрифты гружу с гугла с помощью WebFont loader.

```
WebFont.load({
    google: {
        families: ['Lobster::latin,cyrillic', 'Marck+Script::latin,cyrillic']
    },
    active: function() {
        var itext = new fabric.IText('абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфцшщьыъэюя', {
        fontFamily: 'Lobster',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        textDecoration: 'normal',
        top: 200,
        left: 0
      });
      canvas.add(itext).renderAll();
      itext.setCoords();
})
```

Все версии самые свежие. При создании объекта IText bounding box объекта не совпадает по ширине. Либо границы объекта слишком большие либо наоборот текст не влезает. Происходит так не со всеми шрифтами и даже не со всеми длинами строк. Если кто использовал такую связку, подскажите, пожалуйста. Ниже фиддл для воспроизведения проблемы.
https://jsfiddle.net/cheeseq/mzbck8nv/2/